# Eigenvector eigenvalue

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematics, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

If $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1& 0 \\ 0 &-1\end{array}\right)$, 
what will be the eigenvalue and eigenvector? Let me know how to solve it.
I am facing difficulty in finding the eigenvector.

Answer (score 3):

Since your matrix is diagonal, your eigenvalues are simply the diagonal elements, namely $\lambda=1$ and $\lambda=-1$ and your eigenvectors form the canonical basis of your space, hence $v_1=(1,0)$ and $v_2=(0,1)$.

If you need the general method you have to proceed like this:

i) to find eigenvalues you have to solve ${det}(A-\lambda I)=0$, where A is your matrix, $\lambda$ is your unknown variable (hence your eigenvalue) and $I$ is the identity matrix.

ii) to find eigenvectors you have to search for the vectors $v\in ker(A-\lambda I)$, hence for the vectors that solve $(A-\lambda I)v=0$.